# Text box focusout event and enter issues in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, jquery-events, jquery-focusout

I have a text input and one button of type submit adjacent to the input. I have bound `focusout` event-handler to the input and click event-handler to the button. Now when I focus on the input and then press `enter`, the `focusout` event-handler gets triggered and the buttons-event handler gets triggered. I want to trigger `focusout` only when text box focus is lost. What should I do ?

Code :-

```
 <div >
     <span>Local Currency: </span>
     <input type='text' id='txtFocusElement'  />
     <button id="btnClickElement" >
         <span> Add new line</span>
     </button>
 </div>
```

I used selector as:

```
 $("#txtFocusElement").bind("focusout", function() {
      console.log('focusout');
 })
 $("#btnClickElement").bind("click", function() {
      console.log('click');
 })
```

and written above code in one function which I call at the time of loading document.

Comment: You could post the relevant jQuery too.

Answer (score 1):

Its IE9 issue with the HTML button tag.

So we should try it with HTML input tag with attribute type as button.

above code can be rewritten as :

```
<div >
     <span>Local Currency: </span>
     <input type='text' id='txtFocusElement'  />
     <input id="btnClickElement" type="button" value="Add new line" />
</div>
```

Using this my problem gets solved .

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the selector to input[type=text].
This will only get triggered when you focus out on a text field.

Comment: I tried with the id of that text box for binding event as i have other text boxes in my UI to which i need to bind key down event for enter and escape keys only but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach to a `mouseup` event instead of `click`, that is the only solution I see for now

You can also add a check for mouse button which was pressed, so it wouldn't fire if user would press a right button

```
var ClickElementEventHandler = function(e) {
    if (e.which != 1) return;
    //your code
};

$("#btnClickElement").bind("mouseup",ClickElementEventHandler)
```